# How to disable Asian IME for QTextEdit?

Tags: python, qt, keyboard, pyqt, ime

I am developing a language-learning system in `PyQt4` and have written an embedded virtual keyboard for every language available in the program. I'm only testing the program on Windows for now.
The problem is that when an Asian IME is selected (such as MS New Quick, Google Pinyin, Sogou, Cangjie etc.), I cannot rid of it, it continues overriding all key presses when the focus is in `QTextEdit`.

I tried this when subclassing QTextEdit:

```
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_InputMethodEnabled, False)
```

Tried overriding `inputMethodEvent` and `inputMethodQuery` in my subclass.
Surely, the `keyPressEvent` is overridden, otherwise I wouldn't be able to implement the virtual keyboard.

I also tried this:

```
class customInputContext(QInputContext):

    def __init__(self, parent = 0):
        QInputContext.__init__(self, parent)
        print('qinputcontext initialized')

    def reset(self):
        pass

    def filterEvent(self, event):
        if event.type()==QEvent.RequestSoftwareInputPanel:
            print('input panel requested')
            event.accept()
            return QInputContext.filterEvent(self, event)
        else:
            return QInputContext.filterEvent(self, event)

class MyQApplication(QApplication):

    def __init__(self, args):
        QApplication.__init__(self, args)
        self.setInputContext(customInputContext(parent = self))
        self.setAutoSipEnabled(False)
```

And STILL I always see the IME panel when I try to type something in the `QTextEdit`. So how do I disable the IME for it, when I don't need it?